# How to write the code in java to get the desired output?

Tags: java, output

If the value of x is 29 then the desired output is 0
If the value of x is 3 then the desired output is 1
If the value of x is 1 then the desired output is 4
If the value of x is 2 then the desired output is 2

Comment: I hope you *do* know about [`if`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) but you're not allowed to use them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to write `if (x == something) return someValue;`

Comment: See [Oracle Java Tutorial: The if-then and if-then-else Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) and [The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: I think you already get the answers if you know **if**?

Comment: Have you heard of [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statements!!!!

Comment: Instead of "changes should be made" the question should say "how to *write*.." - but alas, that is the flaw in the question: requesting a task. (I suspect the answer involves [*bit manipulation*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) since it's a 'puzzle', presumably one without conditionals or lookups.)

Comment: Yes it is a puzzle so only using if else won't solve the problem. I want to know how to solve this problem. Thanks for the edit suggestion @user2864740

Comment: You haven't made it clear what there is to puzzle out.  There is clearly something you expect which you haven't stated.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by a "puzzle". Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You could use if/else or switch statement or a Random number generator.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int i : new int[] { 29, 3, 1, 2, -2})
        System.out.println(i+": "+puzzle(i));
}

public static int puzzle(int n) {
    return new Random(3147 * n).nextInt(7) - 2;
}
```

prints

```
29: 0
3: 1
1: 4
2: 2
-2: -2
```

The **real question** should be; What does the person marking this answer expect you to do based on what you have been taught?

Comment: No this won't solve the problem because it is a puzzle. Like x = 4 will produce 1 or x= -2 will produce -2

Comment: @SajidHossain You are describing a function, not a puzzle.  There is nothing to puzzle out except how to code it to do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @PeterLawrey How did you determine the values used in the random approach?

Comment: @user2864740 brute force trying different values. Took longer to get the code right than it took to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static int puzzle(int x)
    {
        if(x == 29)
            return 0;
        if(x == 3)
            return 1;
        if(x == 1)
            return 4;
        if(x == 2)
            return 2;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: No this won't solve the problem because it is a puzzle. Like x = 4 will produce 1 or x= -2 will produce -2